# host files comments out my laravel domain

Tags: php, laravel, hosts

I am currently debugging my application in a local sever (homestead) from laravel. One of its instructions is to edit etc/hosts file to include the domain of your laravel application with a loop back address. When I add my domain it works for several minutes (45 minutes is the longest so far.) but after that the hosts file automatically comments out the line of my domain with a #.

I always repeat the process every time when it gets automatically commented out. Is it normal ? is there a way to permanently add my domain there ?
Btw. Im running on Windows 8.1

Comment: edit host file in sudo !

Comment: I always edit it by running it as administrator. (That is the only way you can save it as is.) But still get the same result.

Comment: Are you running an internet security suite or something that might be overriding it?

Comment: If your running BitDefender or something similar thats probably the culprit see this post https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/why-dose-vagrant-comment-out-my-hosts-file

Comment: Hi @MarkDavidson, Yes I am running BitDefender. Thanks for the link, this is probably the same situation.